# How to plot glht() confidence intervals with ggplot()?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, data-visualization, ggplot2

Using `glht()` from the `multcomp` package, one can calculate the confidence intervals of different treatments, like so ([source](https://arc.lib.montana.edu/book/statistics-with-r-textbook/item/60#Linear%20Hypotheses%3A%0AEstimate%09lwr%09upr%0AAverage%20-%20Beautiful%20%3D%3D%200%09-0.3596%09-2.2968%091.5775%0AUnattractive%20-%20Beautiful%20%3D%3D%200%091.4775%09-0.4729%093.4278%0AUnattractive%20-%20Average%20%3D%3D%200%091.8371%09-0.1257%093.7999%0A)):

```
Simultaneous Confidence Intervals

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts

Fit: lm(formula = Years ~ Attr, data = MockJury)

Quantile = 2.3749

95% family-wise confidence level
Linear Hypotheses:
                                Estimate  lwr       upr
Average - Beautiful ==      0   -0.3596   -2.2968   1.5775
Unattractive - Beautiful == 0    1.4775   -0.4729   3.4278
Unattractive - Average ==   0    1.8371   -0.1257   3.7999
```

These intervals can then be visualized using `plot()`:
[image: Confidence interval plot]

Is it possible to plot these intervals using `ggplot()` (for consistency and aesthetics)? If so, how?

If not, is there a workaround to make the output resemble a `ggplot()` chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the output of `confint` to a data frame, then you can directly plot the output in ggplot2. Here's an approach (using a `glht` example from the help file) that uses the `tidy` function from `broom` to convert `confint()` output to a data frame suitable for plotting:

```
library(multcomp)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

lmod <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)

m = glht(lmod, linfct = c("Agriculture = 0",
                          "Examination = 0",
                          "Education = 0",
                          "Catholic = 0",
                          "Infant.Mortality = 0"))

confint(m) %>% 
  tidy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lhs, y=estimate, ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="11", colour="grey60") +
    geom_errorbar(width=0.1) + 
    geom_point() +
    coord_flip() +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** In response to the comment...

**Curved ends for the confidence intervals**

I'm not sure of an easy way to add curved ends to the errorbars, by you can come close by using `geom_segment` and arrows with a shallow arrowhead angle.

```
confint(m) %>% 
  tidy %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=lhs, y=estimate)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="11", colour="grey60") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=lhs, y=conf.low, yend=conf.high), size=0.4, 
               arrow=arrow(ends="both", length=unit(0.05, "inches"), angle=70)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

**`lhs` ordering**

In terms of ordering, `lhs` will be ordered alphabetically unless it is converted to a factor with a specific order. For example, below we order by the value of `estimate`.

```
confint(m) %>% 
  tidy %>% 
  arrange(estimate) %>% 
  mutate(lhs = factor(lhs, levels=unique(lhs))) %>%   # unique() returns values in the order they first appear in the data
  ggplot(aes(x=lhs, y=estimate)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="11", colour="grey60") +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=lhs, y=conf.low, yend=conf.high), size=0.4, 
               arrow=arrow(ends="both", length=unit(0.05, "inches"), angle=70)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, eipi10—this looks great! I had a small follow-up: is it possible to list the lhs in alphabetical order? I tried by inserting ```%>% arrange(desc(lhs))``` into the pipe, but it did not work (despite working in the tidy table). OTOH, really nitpicky, but want to confirm: I looked through the documentation on geom_errorbar() and I didn't see a way to make the error bars curved (like the original chart)—am I right to assume it's not possible?

Comment: Grand, thanks! The code as written didn't work (as per the comment above), but I changed ```arrange(estimate)``` to ```arrange(desc(lhs))``` and then all good :). Thanks very much!

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you want to order by the coefficient values (the `estimate` column in this case) or just reverse the alphabetical order of the `lhs` values.

Comment: One more follow-up, not sure if should be its own question: when I try to create an interactive chart with ggplotly(ggplotchart), the line at 0 get's chopped, as do the arrows. Is there a workaround, or is that simply the nature of the beast?